# Different size for the same view on CouchDB

Tags: performance, database-design, view, couchdb

I have two databases with similar data (organized differently) and I've created a view for each one returning the same response. I have notice that the time response of the query is different even returning the same response, one being 3182ms, other being 217ms approximately, having queried 5 times. 
I query both using:

```
curl -x GET ...db1/_design/query1/view/q1?group=true and
curl -x GET ...db2/_design/query1/view/q1?group=true.
```

I have checked the data sizes of the design documents using `curl -x GET ...db1/_design/query1/_info.` The design data size of the first is 146073878 bites and the second is 3739596 bites.
I thought both should have the same size, because they return the same view, and i havent used any filters, both views beeing equal.
Somebody can explain me why the same view created by different databases have different sizes?

My data is organized using two differents roots, but the same data, changing only the root:

Customer data in the root:

```
{
   "c_customer_sk": 65836,
   "c_first_name": "Frank",
   "c_last_name": "White",

   "store_sales": [
       {
           "ss_sales_price": 20.24,
           "ss_ext_sales_price": 1012,
           "ss_coupon_amt": 0,
           "date": [
               {
                   "d_month_seq": 1187,
                   "d_year": 1998
               }
           ],
           "item": [
               {
                   "i_item_sk": 10454,
                   "i_item_id": "AAAAAAAAGNICAAAA",
                   "i_item_desc": "Results highlight as patterns; so right years show. Sometimes suitable lips move with the critics. English, old mothers ought to lift now perhaps future managers. Active, single ch",
                   "i_current_price": 2.88,
                   "i_class": "romance",
                   "i_category_id": 9,
                   "i_category": "Books"
               }
           ]
       },
       {
            "ss_sales_price": 225,
           "ss_ext_sales_price": 1023,
           "ss_coupon_amt": 0,...
```

View function for customer in the root:

```
function(doc) 
{ 
   for each (store_sales in doc.store_sales) {
var s=store_sales.ss_ext_sales_price;
if(s==null){s=0}
for each (item in store_sales.item){
 var item_id=item.i_item_id;
 var item_desc=item.i_item_desc;
 var category=item.i_category;
 var class=item.i_class;
 var price=item.i_current_price;}
 if(category=="Music" || category=="Home" || category=="Sports"){
        for each (date in store_sales.date){
            var g=date.d_month_seq;}
            if (g>=1200 && g<=1211){
               emit({item_id:item_id,item_desc:item_desc, category:category, class:class, current_price:price},s);
        }   
   }}}

reduce:_sum
```

Example of answer: 
key:
{"item_id": "AAAAAAAAAAAEAAAA", "item_desc": "Rates expect probably necessary events. Circumstan", "category": "Sports", "class": "optics", "current_price": 3.99}

Value:
106079.49999999999

Item data in the root:

```
{
  "i_item_sk": 10454,
  "i_item_id": "AAAAAAAAGNICAAAA",
  "i_item_desc": "Results highlight as patterns; so right years show. Sometimes suitable lips move with the critics. English, old mothers ought to lift now perhaps future managers. Active, single ch",
  "i_current_price": 2.88,
  "i_class": "romance",
  "i_category_id": 9,
  "i_category": "Books",
   "store_sales": [
       {
           "ss_sales_price": 20.24,
           "ss_ext_sales_price": 1012,
           "ss_coupon_amt": 0,
           "date": [
               {
                   "d_month_seq": 1187,
                   "d_year": 1998
               }
           ],
           "customer": [
               { 
                   "c_customer_sk": 65836,
                   "c_first_name": "Frank",
                   "c_last_name": "White",
               }
           ]
       },
       {
            "ss_sales_price": 225,
           "ss_ext_sales_price": 1023,
           "ss_coupon_amt": 0,...
```

View for item on root:

```
function(doc) 
{ 
var item_id=doc.i_item_id;
 var item_desc=doc.i_item_desc;
 var category=doc.i_category;
 var class=doc.i_class;
 var price=doc.i_current_price;
  if(category=="Music" || category=="Home" || category=="Sports"){
for each (store_sales in doc.store_sales) {
var s=store_sales.ss_ext_sales_price;
if(s==null){s=0}
        for each (date in store_sales.date){
            var g=date.d_month_seq;}
            if (g>=1200 && g<=1211){
               emit({item_id:item_id,item_desc:item_desc, category:category, class:class, current_price:price},s);
        }   
   }}} 

 reduce:_sum
```

Returning the same answer.

I have made the cleanup and compaction of the designs and the time response of the database which the itens data are in the root is much faster, and the sizes of the data size is smaller too, but I dont know why.
Can someone explain me?

Answer (score 0):

could it be a difference of database compaction? When you replicate an existing databases to an empty one, only the last revision of each documents are sent to the new one, making it potentially way lighter. [The same applies to views](https://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Compaction)

Comment: Hi @maxlath. This is not my case, I'm not updating the views, they are the same always, I'm not inserting data on each data base, thats why they dont change. The data on each database is fixed. But I'll make a clean up  and see what happens.

Comment: Hi @maxlath, I have added some examples. Maybe you can understand better now.